# How to use Jquery UI to perform drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I an new to `Jquery ui` `drag` here and I have a question.

I am trying to `drag` the element in my `DOM` and I use the following codes

```
dragObj = document.getElementsByClassName('drag');
$(dragObj).draggable();
```

I can `drag` the element but the element sticks to my mouse and I am not sure how to put it down…etc. I read the `Jquery` ui `draggable` document and it doesn't tell me much. Would someone here help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can simplify your code to just `$('.drag').draggable()` so you're saying you can move it but then when you release the left click it stills follows your mouse movements?

Comment: Do any of these examples do what you want?:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @koala_dev yes that's correct

Comment: @3dgoo that's what I was reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of draggable() is that the element drops on mouseup.

Maybe you're interrupting the mouseup event on that element somewhere in your code?
I managed to replicate your symptoms buy calling `stopPropagation` on mouseup.

Also make sure you don't have any javascript errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/vQ9Y5/

```
$('div').draggable();

$('div').mouseup(function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I went to your jsfiddle and i still can't put the element donw. weird. +1

Comment: @FlyingCat comment that `ev.stopPropagation()` and it will work - Andy demonstrated what possibly you could have done in your code

Comment: @FlyingCat I'm sorry if it wasn't clear from my answer. sansix is correct, without more of your code we can only speculate what the problem could be. I found that `stopPropagation` (or `return false` for that matter) inside a mouseup eventhandler could cause your problem.